# Microsoft C exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0017F5E0

Tags: c++

I am writing a hangman game. I am getting this error:Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0017F5E0. When I step through the program it stops here and the output window gives me this error: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0017F5E0 and I see the message "error reading characters of string.

this is my code

```
void Player::boardSetup()
{
    unsigned seed =time(0);
    srand(seed);
    word=rand()%100;
    Words1[word]=Word1;
    strcpy_s(Copy,Word1.c_str());

    size=strlen(Word1.c_str());
    for(index=0;index<size;index++)
    {
        Guess[index]='-';
        cout<<Guess[index]<<endl;
    }


}
```

Here is all my code. I hope this helps so you do not have to guess.
class Player

```
{   public:
    string fName;
     string lName;
     int DOB;
     string username;
     int SS4;
     string email;
     int won;
     int lost;
     const int static  WordSIZE=15;
     int const static totalWORDS=100;
     string static Letters[WordSIZE];
     string static  Words1[totalWORDS];
     char static   Copy[WordSIZE];
     char static Guess[WordSIZE];
     int index;
     int word;
     int size;
     int isComing;//I need function to initialize these.
     char letter;
     bool correct;//I need a function to initialize these.
     string Word1;
public:
    Player(string,string,int,string,int,string);
    void getWords();
    void boardSetup();
    void playGame();
    void deathBed(int);



};

Player::Player(string first,string last,int birth, string nicname,int SS,string mail)
{
 fName=first;
 lName=last;
 DOB=birth;
 username=nicname;
 SS4=SS;
 email=mail;
 isComing=0;
 correct=true;
}
    const int static  WordSIZE=15;
     int const static totalWORDS=100;
  string Player::  Words1[totalWORDS]; 
    char Player::   Copy[WordSIZE];
     char Player:: Guess[WordSIZE];
      string Player:: Letters[WordSIZE];
 void Player::getWords()
{ 





  ifstream WordBank;
  int index=0;
    WordBank.open("C:\\WordBank\\words.txt");


    if(WordBank)
    {
         while(WordBank>>Words1[index])
         {
           index++;
         }
     WordBank.close();
    }
    else
        {
          cout<<"There was an error."<<endl;
        }

}


    /*string *words2;
    words2=new  string[100];
  ifstream WordBank;
  int index;
    WordBank.open("C:\\WordBank\\words.txt");


    if(WordBank)
    {
       for(index=0;(WordBank>>words2[index]);index++)
        {



        }
    WordBank.close();
    }
    else
        {
          cout<<"There was an error."<<endl;
        }
    delete [] words2;
   words2=0;
}*/

void Player::boardSetup()
{
    unsigned seed =time(0);
    srand(seed);
    word=rand()%100;
    Words1[word]=Word1;
    strcpy_s(Copy,Word1.c_str());

    size=strlen(Word1.c_str());
    for(index=0;index<size;index++)
    {
        Guess[index]='-';
        cout<<Guess[index]<<endl;
    }


}






}

void Player::playGame()
{
    while(isComing!=7)
    {
        deathBed(isComing);
        cout<<Guess<<endl;
        cout<< "Please guess a letter."<<endl;// or press 0 to go to the main screen for help
        cin>>letter;
        letter=toupper(letter);

            for (index=0;index<size;index++)
        {
            if(Copy[index]==letter)
            {
               cout<<"Nice Job"<<endl; //add the ability to see the word
               Guess[index]=letter;
               cout<<Guess[index]<<endl;

            }
            else  if(strcmp(Word1.c_str(),Guess)==0)
              {
                  cout<<"You WIN!!!"<<endl;
                  return;
              }

            else if (correct=false)
            {
                cout<<"Please,Try again"<<endl;
                isComing++;
            }
        }

    }
     void deathBed(int isComing);

     cout<<"The word is"<<Words1[word]<<"."<<endl;

     //draw a big red noose. call a function for it.

}


struct userInfo
{
    string FName;
    string LName;
    int dob;
    string Username;
    int ss4;
    string Email;
};

userInfo getUserInfo();


int main()
{ 
  userInfo i; 
     i=getUserInfo();
 Player player1(i.FName,i.LName,i.dob,i.Username,i.ss4,i.Email);
 player1.getWords();
 player1.boardSetup();
 player1.playGame();

    return 0;
}

userInfo getUserInfo()
{
    userInfo info;

    cout<<"What is your first name?"<<endl;
    cin>> info.FName;
    cout<<"What is your last name?"<<endl;
    cin>>info.LName;
    cout<<"What is your date of birth"<<endl;
    cin>>info.dob;
    cout<<"Please enter a user name."<<endl;
    cin>>info.Username;
    cout<<"Please enter the last four digits of your Social Security number."<<endl;
    cin>>info.ss4;
    cout<<"Please enter your email address."<<endl;
    cin>>info.Email;

    return info;
}
```

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debugging information and **use the debugger** ...

Comment: What are Copy, Word1, Guess. Where and more importantly how are they declared?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "compile with all warnings and debugging information and use the debugger." I am using MSVS 2012 to write c++ programs. I have only been learning for 3 months. I am unfamilar with a lot of terminology but I have done a lot of research.

Comment: Copy and Guess are Character Arrays. Word1 is a string array. They are declared as member variables. The are part of class, Player.

Comment: They are not declared in a separate header or .h file they are in-line so to speak.

Comment: i know you guys are busy can you at least point me in the right direction

Comment: Basile already did. If you want to debug your programs, you need to learn how to use the debugger (in your case, the one built into MSVC).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to debug your program, but here are some issues that I found:

**Use `std::vector` not arrays.**
Arrays don't know their size, they can't expand on demand and messy when passing around.

**Use your structures.**
You create a `userInfo` structure only to fill from the input.
Your `Player` class has the same fields as `userInfo`.  You should create a `userInfo` variable in `Player`.
Pass the whole `userInfo` structure to the `Player` constructor.
You could use an *initialization list* to copy the `userInfo` from the constructor parameter to the `userInfo` variable in `Player`.

**Separate your concepts.**
In your present design, the board is embedded into every `Player`.
In `main()`, at least one player must get the board words.
I suggest making a `Board` class.  Each `Player` can give a guess to the `Board` and it can return a response and redraw itself.
The `Board` would be in charge of initializing its word list and choosing a guess.

**Separate themes into separate translation units.**
Put the Player into its own header and source file.
The `main` function should be in a separate source file.
This would allow you to make changes in `main` without recompiling the `Player`.
The concept also helps support *loose coupling*, *encapsulation*, and *data hiding.*

**Let the objects do the work.**
The `userInfo` class should have a method to obtain its member info from the outside world.
A `Board` class should perform work related to the board.
A `Player` class should perform work related to a player.
The `main` function should glue everything together (such as coordinating players).